# Invalid exception messages from parser combinators in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I'm studying functional programming using Haskell language. And as an exercise I need to implement a function parsing a primitive arithmetic expression from `String`. The function must be able to handle double literals, operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` with the usual precedence and parentheses.

```hs
parseExpr :: String -> Except ParseError Expr
```

with next defined data types:

```hs
data ParseError = ErrorAtPos Natural
  deriving Show

newtype Parser a = P (ExceptState ParseError (Natural, String) a)
  deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

data Prim a
  = Add a a 
  | Sub a a 
  | Mul a a 
  | Div a a 
  | Abs a   
  | Sgn a
  deriving Show

data Expr
  = Val Double      
  | Op (Prim Expr)  
  deriving Show
```

Where `ExceptState` is a modified `State` monad, allowing to throw exception pointing at the error position.

```hs
data Annotated e a = a :# e
  deriving Show
infix 0 :#

data Except e a = Error e | Success a 
  deriving Show

data ExceptState e s a = ES { runES :: s -> Except e (Annotated s a) }
```

Also `ExceptState` has defined `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances, which were thoroughly tested earlier, so I am positive in their correctness.

```hs
instance Functor (ExceptState e s) where
  fmap func ES{runES = runner} = ES{runES = \s ->
    case (runner s) of
      Error err   -> Error err
      Success ans -> Success (mapAnnotated func $ ans) }

instance Applicative (ExceptState e s) where
  pure arg = ES{runES = \s -> Success (arg :# s)}
  p <*> q = Control.Monad.ap p q

instance Monad (ExceptState e s) where
  m >>= f = joinExceptState (fmap f m)
    where
      joinExceptState :: ExceptState e s (ExceptState e s a) -> ExceptState e s a
      joinExceptState ES{runES = runner} = ES{runES = \s ->
        case (runner s) of
          Error err -> Error err
          Success (ES{runES = runner2} :# s2) ->
            case (runner2 s2) of
              Error err           -> Error err
              Success (res :# s3) -> Success (res :# s3) }
```

To implement the function `parseExpr` I used basic parser combinators:

```hs
pChar :: Parser Char
pChar = P $ ES $ \(pos, s) ->
  case s of
    []     -> Error (ErrorAtPos pos)
    (c:cs) -> Success (c :# (pos + 1, cs))

parseError :: Parser a
parseError = P $ ES $ \(pos, _) -> Error (ErrorAtPos pos)

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = parseError

  (<|>) (P(ES{runES = runnerP})) (P(ES{runES = runnerQ})) =
    P $ ES $ \(pos, s) ->
      case runnerP (pos, s) of
        Error _     -> runnerQ (pos, s)
        Success res -> Success res

instance MonadPlus Parser
```

which were used to construct more complex ones:

```hs
-- | elementary parser not consuming a character, failing if input doesn't
-- reach its end
pEof :: Parser ()
pEof = P $ ES $ \(pos, s) ->
  case s of
    [] -> Success (() :# (pos, []))
    _  -> Error $ ErrorAtPos pos

-- | parses a single digit value
parseVal :: Parser Expr
parseVal = Val <$> (fromIntegral . digitToInt) <$> mfilter isDigit pChar

-- | parses an expression inside parenthises
pParenth :: Parser Expr
pParenth = do
  void $ mfilter (== '(') pChar
  expr <- parseAddSub
  (void $ mfilter (== ')') pChar) <|> parseError
  return expr

-- | parses the most prioritised operations
parseTerm :: Parser Expr
parseTerm = pParenth <|> parseVal

parseAddSub :: Parser Expr
parseAddSub = do
  x <- parseTerm
  ys <- many parseSecond
  return $ foldl (\acc (sgn, y) -> Op $
    (if sgn == '+' then Add else Sub) acc y) x ys

  where
    parseSecond :: Parser (Char, Expr)
    parseSecond = do
      sgn <- mfilter ((flip elem) "+-") pChar
      y <- parseTerm <|> parseError
      return (sgn, y)

-- | Parses the whole expression. Begins from parsing on +, - level and
-- successfully consuming the whole string.
pExpr :: Parser Expr
pExpr = do
  expr <- parseAddSub
  pEof
  return expr

-- | More convinient way to run 'pExpr' parser
parseExpr :: String -> Except ParseError Expr
parseExpr = runP pExpr
```

As a result, at this point function works as intended if given `String` expression is valid:

```hs
ghci> parseExpr "(2+3)-1"
Success (Op (Sub (Op (Add (Val 2.0) (Val 3.0))) (Val 1.0)))
ghci> parseExpr "(2+3-1)-1"
Success (Op (Sub (Op (Sub (Op (Add (Val 2.0) (Val 3.0))) (Val 1.0))) (Val 1.0)))
```

Otherwise `ErrorAtPos` does not point at the necessary position:

```hs
ghci> parseExpr "(2+)-1"
Error (ErrorAtPos 1)
ghci> parseExpr "(2+3-)-1"
Error (ErrorAtPos 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

My main assumption was that something wrong was with function `(<|>)` of `Alternative Parser` and it incorrectly changed `pos` variable.

```hs
  (<|>) (P(ES{runES = runnerP})) (P(ES{runES = runnerQ})) =
    P $ ES $ \(pos, s) ->
      case runnerP (pos, s) of
        -- Error _     -> runnerQ (pos, s)
        Error (ErrorAtPos pos')     -> runnerQ (pos' + pos, s)
        Success res -> Success res
```

But it led to more strange results:

```hs
ghci> parseExpr "(5+)-3"
Error (ErrorAtPos 84)
ghci> parseExpr "(5+2-)-3"
Error (ErrorAtPos 372)
```

Then more doubts were aimed at `joinExceptState` function of `instance Monad (ExceptState e s)` in spite of everything I've run it through, doubts that it wasn't working on `s` of `(Natural, String)` type as I indented in this case. But then I can't really change it for this concrete type only.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question, although it would have been even better if it really included *all* your code. I filled in the missing pieces:

```hs
mapAnnotated :: (a -> b) -> Annotated s a -> Annotated s b
mapAnnotated f (a :# e) = (f a) :# e

runP :: Parser a -> String -> Except ParseError a
runP (P (ES {runES = p})) s = case p (0, s) of
  Error e -> Error e
  Success (a :# e) -> Success a
```

Why is `parseExpr "(5+)-3"` equal to `Error (ErrorAtPos 1)`? Here's what happens: we call `parseExpr` which (ultimately) calls `parseTerm` which is just `pParenth <|> parseVal`. `pParenth` fails, of course, so we look at the definition of `<|>` to work out what to do. That definition says: if the thing on the left fails, try the thing on the right. So we try the thing on the right (i. e. `parseVal`), which also fails, and we report *the second* error, which is in fact at position 1.

To see this more clearly, you can just replace `pParenth <|> parseVal` with `parseVal <|> pParenth` and observe that you get `ErrorAtPos 2` instead.

This is almost certainly not the behaviour you want. The documentation of Megaparsec's `p <|> q`, [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-4.4.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html), says:

> If [parser] p fails *without consuming any input*, parser q is tried.

(emphasis in original, meaning: parser q is not tried in other cases). This is a more useful thing to do. If you got reasonably far trying to parse a parenthesised expression and *then* got an error, probably you want to report that error rather than complaining that '(' isn't a digit.

Since you say this is an exercise, I'm not going to tell you how to fix the problem. I'll tell you some other stuff, though.

First, this is not your only issue with error reporting. Above we see that `parseVal "(1"` reports an error at position 1 (*after* the problematic character, which is at position 0) whereas `pParenth "(5+)-3"` reports an error at position 2 (*before* the problematic character, which is at position 3). Ideally, both should give the position of the problematic character itself. (Of course, it'd be even better if the parser stated what character it expected, but that's more difficult to do.)

Second, the way I found the problem was to `import Debug.Trace`, replace your definition of `pChar` with

```hs
pChar :: Parser Char
pChar = P $ ES $ \(pos, s) -> traceShow (pos, s) $
  case s of
    []     -> Error (ErrorAtPos pos)
    (c:cs) -> Success (c :# (pos + 1, cs))
```

and mull over the output for a bit. Debug.Trace is sometimes less useful than one hopes, because of lazy evaluation, but for a program like this it can help a lot.

Third, if you modify your definition of `<|>` to match Megaparsec's does, you might need Megaparsec's `try` combinator. (Not for the grammar you're trying to parse *now*, but maybe later.) `try` solves the issue that

```hs
(singleChar 'p' *> singleChar 'q') <|> (singleChar 'p' *> singleChar 'r')
```

fails on the string "pr" with Megaparsec's `<|>`.

Fourth, you sometimes write `someParser <|> parseError`, which I think is equivalent to `someParser` for both your definition of `<|>` and Megaparsec's.

Fifth, you don't need `void`; just ignore the result, it's the same thing.

Sixth, your `Except` seems to just be `Either`.